# Pymc size / indexing issue

Tags: numpy, modeling, bayesian, pymc, mcmc

I am trying to model Kruschke's "filtration-condensation experiment" with pymc 2.3.5. (numpy 1.10.1)
Basicaly there are:

- 4 groups
- each group has 40 individuals
- each individual has 64 Bernoulli trials (correct/incorrect)

What I am modeling:

- each individual's results are Binomial distribution (e.g. 45 correct out of 64).
- my belief about each individual's performance is Beta distribution.
- this Beta distribution is influenced by group to which individual belongs (through parameters A=mu*kappa and B=(1-mu)*kappa)
- my belief about how strong each group's influence is Gamma distribution (kappa variable)
- my belief about each group's average is Beta distribution (mu variable)

The problem:

- when I do modeling with "size=" parameters, pymc get's lost
- when I seperate each distribution manually (no size=) the pymc does good job

I include the code below:

---

### Data

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import pymc as pm
from pymc.Matplot import plot as mcplot
%matplotlib inline

# Data
ncond = 4
nSubj = 40
trials = 64

N = np.repeat([trials], (ncond * nSubj))
z = np.array([45, 63, 58, 64, 58, 63, 51, 60, 59, 47, 63, 61, 60, 51, 59, 45,
61, 59, 60, 58, 63, 56, 63, 64, 64, 60, 64, 62, 49, 64, 64, 58, 64, 52, 64, 64,
64, 62, 64, 61, 59, 59, 55, 62, 51, 58, 55, 54, 59, 57, 58, 60, 54, 42, 59, 57,
59, 53, 53, 42, 59, 57, 29, 36, 51, 64, 60, 54, 54, 38, 61, 60, 61, 60, 62, 55,
38, 43, 58, 60, 44, 44, 32, 56, 43, 36, 38, 48, 32, 40, 40, 34, 45, 42, 41, 32,
48, 36, 29, 37, 53, 55, 50, 47, 46, 44, 50, 56, 58, 42, 58, 54, 57, 54, 51, 49,
52, 51, 49, 51, 46, 46, 42, 49, 46, 56, 42, 53, 55, 51, 55, 49, 53, 55, 40, 46,
56, 47, 54, 54, 42, 34, 35, 41, 48, 46, 39, 55, 30, 49, 27, 51, 41, 36, 45, 41,
53, 32, 43, 33])
condition = np.repeat([0,1,2,3], nSubj)
```

### Does not work

```
# modeling
mu = pm.Beta('mu', 1, 1, size=ncond)
kappa = pm.Gamma('gamma', 1, 0.1, size=ncond)

# Prior
theta = pm.Beta('theta', mu[condition] * kappa[condition], (1 - mu[condition]) * kappa[condition], size=len(z))

# likelihood
y = pm.Binomial('y', p=theta, n=N, value=z, observed=True)

# model
model = pm.Model([mu, kappa, theta, y])
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
#mcmc.use_step_method(pm.Metropolis, mu)
#mcmc.use_step_method(pm.Metropolis, theta)
#mcmc.assign_step_methods()
mcmc.sample(100000, burn=20000, thin=3)

# outputs never converge and does vary in new simulations
mcplot(mcmc.trace('mu'), common_scale=False)
```

### Works

```
z1 = z[:40]
z2 = z[40:80]
z3 = z[80:120]
z4 = z[120:]
Nv = N[:40]
mu1 = pm.Beta('mu1', 1, 1)
mu2 = pm.Beta('mu2', 1, 1)
mu3 = pm.Beta('mu3', 1, 1)
mu4 = pm.Beta('mu4', 1, 1)
kappa1 = pm.Gamma('gamma1', 1, 0.1)
kappa2 = pm.Gamma('gamma2', 1, 0.1)
kappa3 = pm.Gamma('gamma3', 1, 0.1)
kappa4 = pm.Gamma('gamma4', 1, 0.1)

# Prior
theta1 = pm.Beta('theta1', mu1 * kappa1, (1 - mu1) * kappa1, size=len(Nv))
theta2 = pm.Beta('theta2', mu2 * kappa2, (1 - mu2) * kappa2, size=len(Nv))
theta3 = pm.Beta('theta3', mu3 * kappa3, (1 - mu3) * kappa3, size=len(Nv))
theta4 = pm.Beta('theta4', mu4 * kappa4, (1 - mu4) * kappa4, size=len(Nv))

# likelihood
y1 = pm.Binomial('y1', p=theta1, n=Nv, value=z1, observed=True)
y2 = pm.Binomial('y2', p=theta2, n=Nv, value=z2, observed=True)
y3 = pm.Binomial('y3', p=theta3, n=Nv, value=z3, observed=True)
y4 = pm.Binomial('y4', p=theta4, n=Nv, value=z4, observed=True)

# model
model = pm.Model([mu1, kappa1, theta1, y1, mu2, kappa2, theta2, y2, 
                  mu3, kappa3, theta3, y3, mu4, kappa4, theta4, y4])
mcmc = pm.MCMC(model)
#mcmc.use_step_method(pm.Metropolis, mu)
#mcmc.use_step_method(pm.Metropolis, theta)
#mcmc.assign_step_methods()
mcmc.sample(100000, burn=20000, thin=3)
# outputs converge and are not too much different in every simulation
mcplot(mcmc.trace('mu1'), common_scale=False)
mcplot(mcmc.trace('mu2'), common_scale=False)
mcplot(mcmc.trace('mu3'), common_scale=False)
mcplot(mcmc.trace('mu4'), common_scale=False)
mcmc.summary()
```

Can someone please explain it to me why mu[condition] and gamma[condition] does not work? :)

I guess that not splitting thetas into different variables is the problem but cannot understand why and maybe there is a way to pass a shape parameter to size= on theta?

Comment: Or at least confirm that you get same unusual results :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I can confirm that the first version doesn't lead to stable results. What I can't confirm is that the second one is much better; I have seen very different results also with the second code, with values for the first mu parameter varying between 0.17 and 0.9 for different runs.

The convergence problems can be cured by using good starting values for the Markov chain. This can be done by first doing a maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimate, and then starting the Markov chain from there. The MAP step is computationally inexpensive and leads to a converging Markov chain with reproducible results for both variants of your code. For reference and comparison: The values I see for the four mu parameters are around 0.94 / 0.86 / 0.72 and 0.71.

You can do the MAP estimation by inserting the following two lines of code right after the line in which you define your model with "model=pm.Model(...":

```
map_ = pm.MAP(model)
map_.fit()
```

This technique is covered in more detail in Cameron Davidson-Pilon's [Bayesian Methods for Hackers](https://github.com/CamDavidsonPilon/Probabilistic-Programming-and-Bayesian-Methods-for-Hackers), together with other helpful topics around PyMC.